# Vue 3 + Tagify - Use a v-bind binding combined with a v-on listener that emits update:x event instead

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tagify

I have problem with latest vue3(3.3.8) and latest Tagify(4.17.9)
Im trying to use Tagify in Vue 3 but i get error:

```
VueCompilerError: v-model cannot be used on a prop, because local prop bindings are not writable.
Use a v-bind binding combined with a v-on listener that emits update:x event instead.
at /src/components/tagify.vue:2:49
1  |  
2  |    <textarea v-if="mode === 'textarea'" v-model="value"/>
   |                                                  ^^^^^
3  |    <input v-else :value="value" v-on:change="onChange">
4  |
```

How i can fix this?

Comment: Please share some actual code, not just the error message. We don't know the definitions of any of those variables, etc. Preferably, include a [mre].

Comment: Please look this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/tagify-tags-component-vue-example-forked-58mdkm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props are read-only, as the error states.  Use a writable computed property for the v-model as described in the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#component-v-model).

```js
props: {
  mode: String,
  settings: Object,
  modelValue: [String, Array],
},
computed: {
  value: {
    get() {
      return this.modelValue;
    },
    set(value) {
      this.$emit("update:modelValue", value);
    },
  },
},
```

```html
<textarea v-if="mode === 'textarea'" v-model="value" />
<input v-else v-model="value" />
```

[updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tagify-tags-component-vue-example-forked-7lyq9t?file=/src/App.vue).

I also fixed the change event, it should be a normal listener, not binded like a prop.  You'll find the code works now so that when the tags are updated the `onTagsChange` is fired